# Regex works only with a single words not separated by whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this regex that looks for a digit and a character in a word with a minimum length of 4 :

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$
```

it works for :

```
ABCD1
```

but if i have multiple words like :

```
ABCD1 ABCD2
```

it stop working because the whitespace break the regex :/

How can i improve my regex to allow to capture all the words separated by spaces ?

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/S3APfJ/1

Comment: Are you trying to validate a string with whitespace separated alphanumeric words? Or are you extracting the alphanumeric words? Can there be a `ABC1,;ABC2` input? What is the expected output?

Comment: I want to extract all the words that match , ABC1,;ABC2 should not match because i only want digits 0-9 and a-Z characters .

Comment: For example in : "this is a phrase with ABC1 and ABCD2 but no ABC1! "
i want to have "ABC1","ABCD2" only

Comment: Aha, so try `text.split(/\s+/).filter(x => /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$/.test(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `match()` on the input to find all matches:

```js
var input = "1234 ABCD1 ABCD2 ABCDE";
var matches = input.match(/\b(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}\b/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: This outputs "1234" and i only want to match words that contains 1 digit AND 1 character :/

Comment: @JoelPintoRibeiro Sorry I had a slight issue with the lookaheads.  I made a minor change such that they do not cross over to the next word when asserting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
text.split(/\s+/).filter(x => /YOUR_VALIDATION_REGEX/.test(x))
```

NOTE:

- `.split(/\s+/)` - splits the string with whitespace
- `.filter(x => /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$/.test(x)` - fetches the item if it matches your initial regex.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "this is a phrase with ABC1 and ABCD2 but no ABC1!";
const rx = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$/;
console.log(text.split(/\s+/).filter(x => rx.test(x)));
```

The `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$/` performance can be improved if you use

```js
/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$/
```